# ST_Buffer return table without columns

Tags: postgis

When running my buffer over my points, I am losing all columns into my table.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT st_buffer(geom, 100)
INTO gis_osm_pois_buf 
FROM gis_osm_pois;
```

Is there any way to keep my attributes in the new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT a, b, st_buffer(geom, 100) AS geom
INTO gis_osm_pois_buf 
FROM gis_osm_pois;
```

where a, b and possibly c, d are names of other columns in your original table

Comment: Ok, I see but there is no automatic way to collect the columns name? I mean, when I am doing this action with QGIS, I have all in.

Comment: put a * (wildcard) there but it will include your original geom as well

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Comment: `SELECT st_buffer(geom, 100) AS buffer, *
INTO gis_osm_pois_buf 
FROM gis_osm_pois;`

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thanks a lot.